# C - fork() and processes behaviour

Tags: c, fork, pid

I have a small program written in C on linux. It's purpose is to examine the behaviour of the `fork()` call and the resulting child processes

Upon first inspection everything seems simple enough. However

1. Sometimes output is written in a funny order
2. Sometimes the child PPID is '1' not whatever the parent PID is.

I can't find any pattern or correlation between when it works as expected and when it does not.

I think that point 2. is probably caused by the parent process dying before the child process has executed fully. If so, is there a way to stop this from happening.

However I have no idea what is causing point 1.

Code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{

int x = fork();

if (x == 0)
{
    printf("Child:");
    printf ("\nChild PID : %d", getpid());
    printf ("\nChild PPID: %d", getppid());
    printf("\nHello Child World\n");
}

if (x != 0)
{
    printf("Parent :");
    printf ("\nParent PID : %d", getpid());
    printf ("\nParent PPID: %d", getppid());
    printf("\nHello Parent World\n");
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: The order of output cannot be controlled by a normal program - that's the point of parallel processing - the CPU executes both processes simultaneously. So the outputs are usually inter-tweened.

Comment: thanks, write as answer and I can accept. Also what causes child ppid to be 1, not whatever parent pid is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explanation of Behaviour 1:

- The order of output cannot be controlled by the program normally. That's the point of parallel process. The OS decides which process to execute at any point of time and both processes are executed simultaneously (to the human eye).
- Thus the output would generally be inter-tweened.

Explanation of Behaviour 2:

- You guessed that right.
- The parent process has finished before the forked one.
- If you want the parent pid, you can use `waitpid(x, &status, 0)` in the parent process if you need the parent to stay alive till child execution. [This link](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Process-Completion.html) may help you.

Answer (score 3):

this behaviour is seen because of scheduling policy of operating system. if you are aware of process management concepts of os, then if your parent code is running and fork() is encountered, child is created, but if within that time, parent's time slice has not been completed, then parent continues running and if within its time slice, parent executes and terminates, then child becomes orphan precess and after parent process' time slice completes, child's execution starts, thats why getppid() function returns 1, because child is an orphan process and it it now adopted by init process which starts first when operating system boots and is having process id 1.